# Serial data to multiple serial ports over ethernet

Tags: linux, serial-port, replication

After weeks of research and nothing useful coming up I have to ask this:

Is it possible to send serial signals received on a Linux machine over Ethernet to one or more Linux machine serial port?

This is the setup: One device sends serial signals, one or more computers listen on their serial port for those signals (one way comm), in remote locations. I was looking for old computers with serial ports, running Linux, one for the sender and others for the receivers connected in a VPN, using serial-serial cable connection with clients. I do not want to use virtual ports because the computer(s) listening for serial signals can not be connected to the internet. 
Can sound crazy...

Comment: Huh?  Linux machine receives RS-232 and then you want to send it where and how?

Comment: The question is not clear. Are you trying to pass ethernet packets over serial ports? Take a look at PPP.

Comment: I want so send RDS data from one computer to one or more RDS encoders over ethernet. The only way to have dynamic RDS is to feed data to the encoder over serial. So, the Linux machine (server) receives data from serial and then send that data over ethernet (TCP,UDP) to the Linux machine (client). The client then, converts the data to serial and pass that data to the serial port where the RDS encoder is connected.

Comment: Is this question about Electronics or programming?

Comment: If it's programming, what language? Might the python tcp/ip serial bridge code in the pyserial documentation help point you in the right direction?